# How to set the title of DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

This should be a simple task, but for some reason I can find a way to set the title of a [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html). (I am setting the dialog contents using `onCreateView` overload).

The default style leaves a place for the title, but I can't find any method on the `DialogFragment` class to set it.

The title is somehow magically set when the `onCreateDialog` method is used to set the contents, so I wonder if this is by design, or there is a special trick to set it when using the `onCreateView` overload.

Answer (score 316, accepted):

You can use `getDialog().setTitle("My Dialog Title")`

Just like this:

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    ...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Set title for this dialog
        getDialog().setTitle("My Dialog Title");

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mydialog, container, false);
        // ...
        return v;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, indeed getDialog().setTitle() does the trick. After looking at the solution it does make a lot of sense to work that way but for some reason I expected the call to set the title to be on the DialogFragment class itself (same place where setStyle() and DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE are defined). Thank you very much for the solution.

Comment: What if I wanted to change the background of the title.  Is that possible?

Comment: Also note that you can't set the dialog title in the fragment's onCreate() method since the dialog hasn't been created yet :)

Comment: @Rob Holmes I want to set the title from outside of the dialog class (where I create the instance). I.e. MyDialogFragment myFragment = new MyDialogFragment(); myFragment.getDialog().setTitle("myTitle"); myFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "myTitle"); However, it seems as though getDialog() returns null at this point. Is there another way to set the title from here (without making my own setTitle methdo)?

Comment: Also comment out line in onCreateDialog method: //dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: I believe Jason's approach bellow is more correct in the general case.

Comment: If you has spent several hours to figure out why this accepted answer doesn't work, you need to combine it together with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405042/android-dialogfragment-title-not-showing

Answer (score 75):

Does overriding `onCreateDialog` and setting the title directly on the `Dialog` work? Like this:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.setTitle("My Title");
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is better because fragment can be used not only in dialogs

Comment: This solutions is also useful for xamarin.android

Comment: Also see my more recent answer which is based upon the above code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41798042/1617737

Answer (score 15):

[Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5194249/1617737) used to work for me, but now it needs the following additions to get the title to show.

Firstly, in your MyDialogFragment's `onCreate()` method, add:

`setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MyDialogFragmentStyle);`

Then, in your styles.xml file, add:

```
<style name="MyDialogFragmentStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

After hours of trying different things, this is the only one that has done the trick for me.

NB - You may need to change the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert` to something else in order to match the style of your theme.

Comment: Setting `android:windowNoTitle` *`false`* wasn't necessary after switching to `Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatDialogFragment` from `Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment`, nor sufficient as it resulted in duplicate titles (even though I ensured it was being set only once).

Answer (score 2):

DialogFragment could be represented as dialog and as Activity. Use code below that would work properly for both

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (getShowsDialog()) {
        getDialog().setTitle(marketName);
    } else {
        getActivity().setTitle(marketName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html). 
The way i did is like this:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle("My Title");
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
    builder.setView(view);

    return builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Ban Geoengineering's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41798042/2898715), but with a few modifications, so instead of coding what specific theme to use in the `DialogFragment`, I override the default style used by `DialogFragment`s in my `styles.xml`.

set the title in the `androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment`.

```kotlin
class EditBatteryLevelFragment:DialogFragment(),SelfClosingFragment.Host
{
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater:LayoutInflater,container:ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState:Bundle?
    ):View
    {
        // set dialog title
        requireDialog().setTitle(R.string.edit_battery_level__title)

        // .....
        return someView
    }
}
```

in your app theme in `styles.xml`, override `android:dialogTheme`, which is the default style used by `DialogFragment` instances.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">

        <!-- BONUS READING: override material colors here, too https://material.io/develop/android/theming/color -->

        <!-- override DialogFragment theme of those spawned by activities with this theme -->
        <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog</item>

    </style>

    <!-- ... -->
```

also in `styles.xml`, declare the dialog theme that will be used by `DialogFragment` instances. it's important for this style to inherit from `ThemeOverlay` so that it will preserve your app's theme colors.

```xml
    <!-- ... -->

    <!-- define the style for your dialog -->
    <style name="AppTheme.Dialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog">

        <!-- add a minimun width to the dialog, so it's not too narrow -->
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@dimen/abc_dialog_min_width_major</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@dimen/abc_dialog_min_width_minor</item>

        <!-- display the title for dialogs -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

make sure that the activity that is spawning the `DialogFragment` is using the defined `AppTheme`.

Comment: Perfect answer! I only needed `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>` to show the title and make the dialog full width.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using view binding:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = YourDialogXmlBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Your title here")
            .setView(binding.getRoot());
    return builder.create();
}
```