# Dialog layout is different with android 6.0

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-dialog, android-6.0-marshmallow

I've recently updated my app to meet Android M (api 23) new changes and I've noticed that there is a huge change in how dialogs are rendered.

In particular the space reserved to title disappeared and the constraints in terms of width and height are not respected.

This happens for all dialogs and in particular below you can see how the logout dialog of the same build looks installed on a api 22 (left) vs api 23 (right) device.

[image: dialog difference]

How can I achieve to have the same representation on all devices?

Here's the custom xml for the dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="text message"
            android:id="@+id/confirmDialogMessage"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="@color/blue_mp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/confirmDialogNo"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/cancelicon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/confirmDialogYes"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:src="@drawable/okicon"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Dialog is shown in this way:

```
dialog = new Dialog(v.getContext());
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_confirm_refuse_layout);
dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.options_logout));
dialog.show();
```

**EDIT: Could you also explain me why this rendering change occurs between api 22 and api 23?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your parent layout Relative.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="text message"
                android:id="@+id/confirmDialogMessage"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_below="@id/text"
            android:background="@color/secondary_blue" >

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/invite"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:src="@drawable/y_cross_btn"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/close"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_tick_btn"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, but to show the title I found out how to do it from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32711916/5546499

Answer (score 0):

You can change from Linear Layout to Relative Layout while aligning the buttons and change Image Button to Image View.

Attaching the sample code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/pricing_blue" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/confirmDialogNo"
        android:src="@drawable/button_green"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/confirmDialogYes"
        android:src="@drawable/button_green"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```