# setTitle of DialogFragment not working in Android M

Tags: android, dialog, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to set title to DialogFragment which is working fine in below android M but not in M.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes..but I have not found anything useful there.

Comment: Maybe your title text color is same as the title background, try changing the text color.

Comment: Dialog box in Android M and above do not have title box.
Its better you create one different layout for Devices Marshmallow and above with TextView as custom title box.

Comment: @MohammedAtif Is this info available somewhere in Android docs?

Comment: https://material.google.com/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-simple-dialogs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32711916/5471104

Here you can display
but by default its been turned off to comply with latest design rules

Answer (score 1):

```
final AlertDialog diag = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Enter An Administrative Password")
    .setView(R.layout.admin_password_dialog)
    .create();

diag.show();

Button diagButton = (Button) diag.findViewById(R.id.btn_confirmPassword);
diagButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // handle button click
    EditText input = (EditText) diag.findViewById(R.id.edit_adminPassword);
    String s = input.getText().toString();
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have tried this too..still not working.

Comment: TRY this <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert</item>

Comment: I am using DialogFragment for showing alert..bcoz I have to do API call and all in Dialog...So please help me solve this problem with DialogFragment.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try building your own custom appearance dialog:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(Context, R.style.customDialog))
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setMessage("Some message").show();

**In your style:**
<style name="customDialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/txt_color</item>
</style>

**In your colors:**
<color name="txt_color">#ff96f3</color>
```