# App created for Android 1.6 lost it's style in Android 8

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I have an app which I'm developing since Android 1.6, starting with Eclipse and moving to Android Studio later. I did my best to keep the compatibility but recently decided to give up on these 6 people having it installed on Android below 4.0 version. I changed the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 26 and... I lost my styling.

My text is black instead of white:

[image]

So apparently my default app style was switched from dark to light (I guess it was Holo Dark back then?). What can I do to fix this?

I've seen some answers about using styles, colors etc. but I don't have xml's like these because when I started this project, they didn't exist yet.

I'd like to avoid recreating every color and applying it to every element to bring back the old look. What should I do?

Comment: What theme are you using? looks like material light which I think is the default. Change it to material dark

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to go over the whole app and examine each element. Unfortunately things which are default in one API level may have to be set explicitly in the next one (e.g. "do AlertDialogs have a title?", see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32711916/5015207)). But of course you can define styles for certain types of widgets or for the app as a whole in res/values/styles.xml So you do not need to style each component individually